# How do I calculate the electrical resistance for a sodium chloride solution?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrical-resistance, non-linear-systems, electrochemistry

Im doing a paper on how the concentration of sodium chloride in water affects the electrical resistivity of the solution. My teacher told me that I may not be able to use $R = V/I$ for this as sodium chloride is non-ohmic is there any other equation I could use or could I still use $R=V/I$? My voltage read was between 8.9 - 8.3V and my current was 0.3 - 1.9A.

Answer (score 1):

A non-ohmic conductor is one where there resistance (*defined* by $R=V/I$) is not constant for different voltages or currents.
If there is a chance the solution is non-ohmic, you need to use a fixed voltage (if you are measuring current) or current (if you are measuring voltage) to measure how $R$ changes with sodium chloride concentration.
I'd recommend measuring the resistance for several significantly different voltages (or currents if that is your independent variable) for each concentration, so you can later plot the resistance changes with concentration for each voltage setting. If the different voltages give different resistances for the same concentration, then the solution is non-ohmic.